django using aggregate() and distinct() together
I have a filterset that has following attributes:
dosFromGte = filters.DateFilter(method="search_by_dos_from_gte", lookup_expr="gte")
dosToLte = filters.DateFilter(method="search_by_dos_from_lte", lookup_expr="lte")

# One of these methods:

def search_by_dos_from_lte(self, queryset: Chart, name: str, value: str) -> Chart:
    return queryset.annotate(max_dos=Min("diagnosis__dos_from")).filter(max_dos__lte=value)

# using annotate and aggregate Min().

I need to run few annotations and then only fetch distinct ids.
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset().exclude(state__in=repo_exclude))
queryset = queryset.annotate(
            ChartId=F("chart_id")
        ).values(
            "ChartId"
        ).distinct("id")

When I apply these filters ?clientId=11&project=56&dosFromGte=2023-08-17&dosToLte=2023-08-19 this tries to run Min() and then distinct on ids.
This gives NotImplementedError("aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.")
So I tried to work around a bit and
queryset.values(
            "id", "ChartId"
        )
# remove duplicate charts based on pk, i.e. id
df = df.drop_duplicates('id')
df = df.drop('id', axis=1)

which kind of felt like a hack and dirty work around.
Is there a cleaner ORM way to do it?

Remove the .distinct('id'), you drop the items with the df?

@willeM_VanOnsem yeah.. seems like that worked too! :D

The main question seem to be why you use MemberId, MemberName, which are (probably) a one-to-many relation, but then you "drop" these, since you have uniqness filtering on the Id... This is essentially what is causing it, the values/annotates with a one-to-many relation.

this was how it was implemented. I just need to get those filters working.

but there is no need to add items to the .values(...) to filter on these...

ok I updated the post now.
but the question is, is the correct way to do?
